# AngularJS shows model text before compilation despite ng-cloak

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, ngcloak

I'm working on a page that has to run on an embedded android system (in the system webview), and this thing is tragically slow. So slow in fact, that when you load a page, somtimes the model text is still on the page for a good half second before AngularJS gets around to updating all of the bindings. This is annoying and clearly undesirable.

I've added `ng-cloak` to endless permutations of elements of the page. I've also added the following style to the style sheet:

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

It just doesn't want to cloak the contents, and I think ionic is to blame. Not knowing a lot about AngularJS, I tried writing a directive `my-cloak` that added a class to the element on compile and pre-link and removed it on post link. It worked better, but it didn't work always.

I've read about some more things I could do like "decorating" the interpolation function (getting out of my depth) and maybe one of the various suggestions listed [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/734) (like evalAsync or something like that) but I don't know enough about Angular to understand what those solutions actually do. Coming from a jQuery background is very hard when transitioning to AngularJS.

So any help would be really appreciated. I just want to prevent the undigested text from ever showing on the screen, basically doing what ng-cloak is supposed to do but for slower systems. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer you are looking for, but there is a good practice to write

```
<span ng-bind="data">&nbsp;</span>
```

(so no {{data}} blinking).

- ng-cloak styles already on the page. Look in the header of rendered page with angular app.
- you can do something like:

`<body ng-show="loaded"></body>` and set `scope.loaded = true` in controller, after data is loaded.